# Is there a suffix to form a noun from an adverb?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, suffixes

I want to know if we have a suffix which can be added to an adverb to form a noun. I have searched about that and I could not find anything about it.

Comment: I can't think of any, exactly. For a -ly adverb, you can generally just take the corresponding adjective and use the basic suffix for turning adjectives to nouns, *-ness*. So "My computer is updating **slow**ly today" --> "the **slow**ness of my computer when updating today." Is that the sort of thing you were thinking of? What type of noun do you want to form?

Comment: English is almost entirely need-, convenience- and affection-driven rather than neat-little-rule–driven. Productivity is to a greater or lesser degree  idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **No,** there is no suffix which can be added to an adverb to form a noun.

There is the noun-forming suffix *-ness* which can be added to many **adjectives:** *hard/hardness, red/redness,* etc, but it doesn't apply to all (*strongness* is *strength*) and it doesn't apply to adverbs.

Even where *fast* might be an adverb meaning *quickly* (as opposed to an adjective meaning *solidly attached*) the noun would be *speed.* For an adverb like *beautifully,* the noun is *beauty.* For an adverb like *quickly,* you **might** get away with *quickness,* (where you replace *-ly* with the nouning suffix *-ness*), but generally there is a more specific non-derived word to use, like *speed* or *rapidity*.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix '-ness' is defined in the OED as forming *abstract* nouns from adverbs:

> Forming abstract nouns from adjectives, participles, adjectival phrases, and (more rarely) nouns, pronouns, verbs, and **adverbs**.

["-ness, suffix". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126245?rskey=ibqMh4&result=4&isAdvanced=false (accessed November 06, 2015). Emphasis mine.]

The OED lexicographers do not example the particular case of nouns formed from adverbs in the historical quotes, but rather content themselves there by showing some of the nonce-uses attested since 1800. Such uses presumably include adverb-to-noun formations, because the suffix is used freely to form nouns; however, in all cases where an adverb has a corresponding adjectival form or sense, the adjective seems to be selected by preference as the noun-formative base.

Also, although perhaps it is a slantwise formation process, I found some evidence indicating that nouns are formed from the adverbs in verbal phrases (that is, verb+adverb):

> Noun suffixes will form nouns from every type of word.
>   ...
>   -er = object, agency or means performing the task of: fixer-upper, do-gooder; added to: verbal phrases (verb+adverb) ....

(From ["Word formation process"](http://www.translationdirectory.com/article37.htm).)